# What is the benefit to use Docker for Django and Channels?

Tags: django, docker, web-hosting

I'm developing a Django web app with Channels. While I'm following this [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) , it is required to install Docker.

I'm working on WSL on windows 10 HOME, and so, it is really painful to install Docker.

I just discover Docker, I'm a little confuse about it, I understand it is a tool which facilitates the deployment of a web app on a web hosting later. But I'm not sure.

Could you give me your advice ? Could you tell me if it is really important to use Docker for my project ?

Would Have I less pain if I would develop on a Ubuntu OS ?

Thank you,

Comment: If you wanna feel yourself as human don't use docker on windows.

Comment: They use docker only to avoid installing redis. You could install Redis to the host instead.

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN for your answer :)

Comment: @Bunyk thank you for your answer ! Is it complicate to install Redis on the server of a web hosting ?

Comment: And, could you tell me if Ubuntu would be easier to use Docker ? I mean, to be on a Ubuntu workstation.

Comment: Redis install should not be complicated on hosting server, that servers usually use Linux. Yes, docker on Ubuntu is a lot less pain than on Windows, last year 3 my coworkers migrated from Windows to Ubuntu just to be able to run our dockerized microservices.

Comment: Thank you @Bunyk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are my own considerations, not pretending to be exhaustive Docker review.

Moving to Docker would give you following advantages:

- Easy deploy - you don't need to supply manuals on how to install your app, dependencies and link them together. Only How to install Docker (btw for Windows it hurts:)
- Isolation - your services get isolated network and do not bother the host
- Easy upgrade - just push new image and that's it
- Decomposition - with `docker-compose` and other tools you will be able to split your application into services and maintain them separately
- Scaling - with proper design, tools like `k8s` will allow you to easily scale app by adding replicas of your services

From the other hand, on Windows Docker create additional overhead, unlike Linux where it is implemented on top of Linux kernel, also you need Win10 Professional to enjoy Docker and not docker toolbox.

Also Windows is not so good in automated package management and installing software for Windows in many cases cannot be done as simple as `apt-get install whatever`, thus you loose another Docker benefit - easy system preparation via Dockerfile.

If you plan to stay only on Windows, based on my own exp I would probably **not** recommend moving to Docker, because I personally found it difficult to use without  VirtualBox/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer ! May I abuse by asking you : I'm using redis-server (for websocket backstore) and virtualenvwrapper to develop my Django web application. For the moment I don't know a lot about Docker (I'm sudying), but, could you tell me if I should wrap all these developments inside of Docker ? :-) Thanks again if you can bright me.

Comment: `redis` as most of databases is wrapped easily. Just use official image and set data store path together with user/password. On Django I cannot comment - didnt use it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise !